# Methods to compute a Sturm sequence

Tags: polynomials, roots

Are there any known methods of computing a [Sturm sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem) of a polynomial $p$ other than the standard algorithm of applying Euclid's algorithm to $p$ and $p'$?

I am asking this question because I noticed that Euclid's algorithm is numerically unstable when implemented with floating point numbers. (See also my related [question](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/8136/ray-tracing-implicit-surfaces-using-sturms-theorem) on the Computer Graphics StackExchange)

Answer (score 1):

[Gleyse (1997)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0893-9659(97)00022-0) used the sequence
$$
\begin{align*}
p_0&=\sum_{i=0}^n a_iT_i\\
p_1&=\sum_{i=1}^n a_iU_{i-1}\\
p_2&=T_1p_1-p_0\\
p_{k+1}&=U_1p_k-p_{k-1},\quad k\geq 2
\end{align*}
$$
instead of Euclid algorithm.

Comment: Is this really a Sturm sequence? Consider the polynomial $p_0(x) = 62 + 485x + 779x^2 + 1000x^4$ for example. Then $a_0 = 1653/2$, $a_1 = 485$, $a_2 = 1779/2$, $a_3 = 0$, $a_4 = 125$ and $p_1(x) = 485 + 1279x + 1000x^3$. But $\mathrm{sign}(p_1)(z) > 0$ and $\mathrm{sign}(p_0')(z) < 0$ for the smallest real root $z$ of $p_0$.

Comment: @Chris Remember $T_i$ and $U_i$ are the Chebyshev polynomials of first and second kinds respectively,

Comment: Yes, I did the computations above with the Chebychev polynomials. The values $a_0,\ldots,a_4$ are the coefficients of the decomposition of the polynomial $p_0$ into the Chebychev polynomials of the first kind, as given in your answer and the paper. Nevertheless $p_1$ and $p_0'$ have a different sign at the smallest real root $z$ of $p_0$, which contradicts the second property of Sturm chains (as given in the Wikipedia article).

Comment: I asked this in a new question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2959586/sturm-sequence-computation-using-chebyshev-polynomials